# Does an ideal $I=(x_1,...,x_n)$ which contains a regular element implie $x_i$ is regular for some $i$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring. $I=(x_1,...,x_n)$ is an ideal. Suppose $I$ contains a $R$-regular element. Does this imply that $x_i$ is $R$-regular for some $i$?

If not, is this true for Noetherian ring or Noetherian local ring?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, let $R=\mathbb{C}[\![x,y]\!]/(xy)$.  This is a commutative Noetherian local ring.  Take $I=(x,y)$, which is the unique maximal ideal of $R$.  Then both $x$ and $y$ are zero divisors as $xy=0$ in $R$.  But the depth of $R$ is $1$, since $\mathbb{C}[\![x,y]\!]$ has depth $2$ and $xy$ is a nonzerodivisor on $\mathbb{C}[\![x,y]\!]$, so $I$ contains a nonzerodivisor of $R$.

More concretely, the associated primes of $R$ are exactly $(x)$ and $(y)$ so anything outside their union is a nonzerodivisor of $R$, e.g. $x+y$.

Answer (score 0):

In the ring of matrix take

$x_{1} = 
\left(
\begin{array}{lcr}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{array}
\right) $

$x_{2} = 
\left(
\begin{array}{lcr}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right) $

Then $Id = 
\left(
\begin{array}{lcr}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)  \in I$

Id is a regular element of $I$, but $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ are not regular elements

Comment: However, the ring of matrices is not commutative.